# Using video (canvas texture) as alpha mask - Three.js

Tags: video, three.js, textures, alpha

I'm trying to use my video canvas texture as mask for a material in Three.js but it's not working. Here is the code I have:

```
video = document.getElementById( 'video' );

texture = new THREE.Texture( video );

var parameters = { color: 0xffffff, mapAlpha: texture },

material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( parameters );
material.transparent = true;
```

Comment: The material blending modes seemed to offer a solution!

Comment: Answer your own question then!